# COUNT with a condition for a query with Group by and Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Requirements:

Table 1:

```
Id      Key          SiteId ItemId    OrderNumber
1       ABCD           X      BTL        NULL
2       BCDE           X      BTL        ABCD
3       CDEF           X      DDD        BSFE
```

Table 2:

```
Id  ItemId    Name
1    BTL      B Prd
2    DDD      D Prd
```

Results Required:

```
Id  ItemId      Name    AvailableKeys
1     BTL      B Prd      1
2     DDD      D Prd      0
```

Available Keys is calculated as the count of Items in table 1 having order numbers as null

Queries tried:

```
1) 
SELECT ps.ItemId, COUNT(ps.ItemId) AS AvailableKeys, item.Name
FROM TABLE1 AS ps 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 as item ON item.ItemId = ps.ItemId 
WHERE ps.SiteId = 'X'
GROUP BY ps.ItemId, item.Name

   -- With this query, I am getting a count of the whole number of items but not the ones having order number as null (Count including even the Unavailable Items)

2) 
    SELECT ps.ItemId, COUNT(ps.ItemId) AS AvailableKeys, item.Name
    FROM TABLE1 AS ps 
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 as item ON item.ItemId = ps.ItemId 
    WHERE ps.OrderNumber IS NULL AND ps.SiteId = 'X'
    GROUP BY ps.ItemId, item.Name

   -- With this query, I am missing the items having **ZERO** available keys
```

Can anyone help me out in building a query to get the required result set from data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, I made the correction in table definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a conditional sum as follows:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN OrderNumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AvailableKeys
```

And the complete query:

```
SELECT item.id, ps.ItemId
    , item.Name
    , SUM(CASE WHEN OrderNumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AvailableKeys
FROM TABLE1 AS ps 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 as item ON item.ItemId = ps.ItemId 
WHERE ps.SiteId = 'X'
GROUP BY item.id, ps.ItemId, item.Name;
```

Returns:

| id | ItemId | ItemName | AvailableKeys |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BTL | B Prd | 1 |
| 2 | DDD | D Prd | 0 |

BTW: You may as well use an `inner join` unless you want to include the case when there is no match in table 2.

Comment: Thanks for your info, I need to include the rows having no match in table2 too.

Comment: @vamsipenta your sample data needs to reflect that then. But as Gordon pointed out, because you've (it seems) joined your tables in reverse order, then  an `inner join` most likely works. But you'd need to add additional sample data to confirm. This query (and Gordons returns the required results from the sample data provided.

Answer (score 1):

You are close with your first query, although the outer join is in the wrong order.  Just add a match in the `ON` clause for the condition you want on the second table:

```
SELECT item.ItemId, COUNT(ps.ItemId) AS AvailableKeys, item.Name
FROM TABLE2 item LEFT JOIN
     TABLE1 ps
     ON item.ItemId = ps.ItemId AND 
        ps.SiteId = 'X' AND
        ps.OrderNumber IS NULL
GROUP BY item.ItemId, item.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item.id, ps.ItemId, item.Name,
    SUM(IIF(OrderNumber IS NULL,1,0)) AS AvailableKeys
FROM 
    TABLE1 AS ps 
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS item ON item.ItemId = ps.ItemId 
WHERE ps.SiteId = 'X'
GROUP BY item.id, ps.ItemId, item.Name;
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Please explain how your solution is different to the existing ones. Why is yours better than the other answers.